# Mail Not Sending When Function Calls Another Function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form tag on my page which leads to a function. If I do a `dd()` in that function the content returns which means it's pointing to that function. Within the function I call a `$this->resendMail()` which is supposed to resend mail.

Within that function, I do a `dd()` on the mail content that is supposed to go and everything returns correctly. All the notes get created but the mail actually isn't even going out.

When I copied that code into my first function, the mail sent perfectly.

Could it be something with calling another function to send mail?

Comment: Please, if you have the code, show it to us. Dont just describe roughly what it does. We cannot debug a description

Comment: Do you have a mail server on this PC? Are you using SendMail? Are you usingPHPMailer? So much is unknown here

Comment: Pro Tip: If your question does not come with a code example, it is probably not On Topic for StackOverflow

Comment: Did you take variable SCOPE into account??

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know I should share my code but I didn't want to due to privacy reasons. I am using MailTrap and Horizon. Also, I found out the issue. For some reasons when you resend the first time it works but the second time it does not. You have to change the content (add a period) and then it resends. Weird bug. I will have to look into Horizon that could be not sending "Duplicates"